# GWT :URL is invalid or violates the same-origin security restriction

Tags: internet-explorer, gwt

Our application uses GWT to create complex UIs but the data is served up by a Coldfusion web server running externally on a different domain.

The code works fine when compiled and deployed in the same domain as the Coldfusion server but gives this error when running in hosted mode when trying to make a Cross Domain AJAX request.

**The URL `http://devxxx/myfile.cfm` is invalid or violates the same-origin security restriction**

*(note:In production it wont be cross domain as the compiled code will reside under the same domain but for hostedmode development the domain is localhost for GWT and devxxxx.com for the server )*

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much research,changing the Security Level to Medium-Low in the Local Intranet zone in IE fixed it for me.

Just leaving this here in case someone walks this path :)

[image]

Comment: thanks did'nt know the IE trick ;) (but still have to try it out tomorrow)

Answer (score 2):

Don't try to work around security, play by the rules: run DevMode "from/on" your dev server.

http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCompilingAndDebugging.html#How_do_I_use_my_own_server_in_development_mode_instead_of_GWT%27s

Answer (score 1):

When you start Google Chrome with

```
--disable-web-security
```

it also doesn't envorce the same origin policy

[Disable same origin policy in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/chrome-disable-same-origin-policy)

For Firefox you can use the Force CORS add on

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/forcecors/

Answer (score 0):

Another reason that causes this behavior is if your remote server is behind a Web Access Firewall (WAF) that causes cors requests to be denied.

The solution that finally worked was to circumvent the WAF by using the direct internal IP in the URL for making AJAX RPC calls instead of the website name.

whew.